# How i can remove a whitespace in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies

Retrieving cookies values to a form i used this:

```
if "HTTP_COOKIE" in os.environ:
    cookies = os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']
    cookies = cookies.split(';')
    print cookies
    for cookie in cookies:
        cookie = cookie.split('=')
        (key,value) = cookie
        if key == "UserID":
            user_id = value
        if key == "Password":
            password = value
```

**printing the values:**

```
print "User ID  = %s" % user_id 
print "Pasword = %s" % password
```

**The problem, only get:**

```
User ID = XYZ
```

**Checking i get that:**

the error is in the cookies string, because in the first condition it get `true` value, but for the rest only get `false`

I print in diferently parts on the code, and get that every list after `UserID` have a whitespace:

```
['UserID=XYZ', ' Password=XYZ123', ' Expires=Tuesday, 31-Dec-2007 23:12:40 GMT', ' Domain=www.tutorialspoint.com', ' Path=/perl', ' PHPSESSID=vgpp18anpc6vb4epi3udkumufp']
```

*How can i strip the cookies for get the key-value pairs without a whitespace?*

**Here is the code:**

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe
import os

print "Set-Cookie:UserID=XYZ"
print "Set-Cookie:Password=XYZ123"
print "Set-Cookie:Expires=Tuesday, 31-Dec-2007 23:12:40 GMT"
print "Set-Cookie:Domain=www.tutorialspoint.com"
print "Set-Cookie:Path=/perl"
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Radio - Fourth CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2> Example </h2>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"


if "HTTP_COOKIE" in os.environ:
    cookies = os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE']
    cookies = cookies.split(';')
    for cookie in cookies:
        cookie = cookie.split('=')
        (key,value) = cookie
        if key == "UserID":
            user_id = value
        if key == "Password":
            password = value
else:
    print "HTTP_COOKIE not set!"

print "User ID  = %s" % user_id
print "Pasword = %s" % password
```

Comment: try `cookie = cookie.strip().split('=')`

Comment: @LeoTao dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was in the strip funcionality.

```
strip():
```

- only removes whitespace in the beginning and in the end of the document.
- only works with strings, not with a list

And this happend:

```
if "HTTP_COOKIE" in os.environ:
    cookies = os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE'] 
    # cookies is now a string
    cookies = cookies.split(';')
    # cookies is now a list
```

The solution is put the strip() afecter cookies first asignation, but the funtion will not remove all whitespaces.

Because that i can use `replace(" ","")`

```
if "HTTP_COOKIE" in os.environ:
        cookies = os.environ['HTTP_COOKIE'] 
        # cookies is now a string without spaces
        cookies = cookies.replace(" ","")
        # cookies is now a list
        cookies = cookies.split(";")
```

---

**Result:**

User ID = XYZ Pasword = XYZ123